# Eloquent multiple unions in same query

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

I have this old query that I want to convert to Eloquent syntax:

```
$query .= "(SELECT *, 3 as `group` FROM mytable_".$table." ORDER BY swordtwo DESC LIMIT 1) UNION";
$query .= "(SELECT *, 4 as `group` FROM mytable_".$table." ORDER BY swordone DESC LIMIT 1) UNION";
$query .= "(SELECT *, 5 as `group` FROM mytable_".$table." ORDER BY axetwo DESC LIMIT 1) UNION";
$query .= "(SELECT *, 6 as `group` FROM mytable_".$table." ORDER BY axeone DESC LIMIT 1) UNION";
$query .= "(SELECT *, 7 as `group` FROM mytable_".$table." ORDER BY spear DESC LIMIT 1) UNION";
$query .= "(SELECT *, 8 as `group` FROM mytable_".$table." ORDER BY morningstar DESC LIMIT 1) UNION";
$query .= "(SELECT *, 9 as `group` FROM mytable_".$table." ORDER BY maul DESC LIMIT 1) UNION";
```

I tried this with Eloquent:

```
$data = $stats->orderBy('crossbow', 'desc')->take(1);
$data = $stats->orderBy('maul', 'desc')->take(1)->union($data);
$data = $stats->orderBy('swordtwo', 'desc')->take(1)->union($data);
$data = $stats->orderBy('swordone', 'desc')->take(1)->union($data);
$data = $data->get();
```

but it always returns a MySQL syntax error.

Is there any way to do this with Eloquent, or do I have to go back to the old style?

Comment: Maybe the easiest way would be to do a raw query https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I solved by using DB::select(DB::raw($my_old_query)).